# What is the Correct Way to Use Crow's Foot Notation for Relationships?

Tags: entity-relationship

This has bothered me for some time. What assumptions are to be made, in regards to cardinality when a relationship does not use crow's foot notation- in my opinion- completely. For example, here is a one-to-many relationship from Wikipedia:

[image]

I would have thought that this in incorrect; that children must have a mother so I would put two lines on the left side (one mandatory and only one) and a 1 to many for the children (a line and a crow's foot) on the right to indicate that a mother must have at least one child, but could have many. I would have expected this:

[image]

My question is, what assumptions are to be made in a "shortcut" like this because I see it everywhere on cardinality examples? Is there a known assumption or rule of what leaving those blank mean?

Comment: If the question is 'what assumptions are to be made', I'd say that there's an assumption on the drawer of the diagram's part that they can communcate their meaning sufficiently without the 'advanced' form of crows foot notation, and on the reader's part that it is only describing the broad relationship. Mothers can have many children. When drawing broad relationships between entities on a whiteboard, we'd rarely use the precise relationship unless it was key to the conversation. What is the wikipedia context to the diagram? would it be important in that situation to be more precise?

Comment: Hi Rich. The issue is that this is almost always in texts, and I chose the Wikipedia one because we could all agree that children must have a mother, so I wonder why they left that out in the diagram. Does that make sense? I'm okay with the shortcuts, but just want to know when to actually do it without distorting the relationship

Comment: I wouldnt' make any assumptions about what is meant if they're using the simplified line styles, other than that they're not using the more complicated line styles.

Comment: Crow's foot notation is not an appropriate choice of notation for relationships in the Entity-Relationship model. In its usual form it doesn't support relationship attributes nor non-binary relationships. It's more suited to representing relationships in network data models, or indicate foreign key constraints in table diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

The difference between them is that Wikipedia's example isn't Crow's Foot, but a variation called Barker Notation. It looks so similar as Richard Barker modelled it on Crow's Foot and intended it as a refinement
(For some reason, they taught us Barker Notation at college as opposed to Crow's Foot)